# ASP.net AJAXControlsToolkit (v15.1) bundling does not seem to work after publishing with Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-bundling

I have an application that I've just updated to use v15.1 of the Ajax Contol Toolkit. I've also used the instructions on this page to configure bundling and everything looks good on my local machine.

https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20use%20bundling%20and%20CDN

If I inspect the source I can see a single script tag with src=/Scripts/AjaxControlToolkit/Bundle?v=.

However, after I publish the website through Visual Studio and upload the site to my live server, bundling doesnt seem to work anymore. Instead I see all the individual resources such as

I've had a look around the net and various forums but I can't see anyone else having a similar problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Everything works, I'm just a bit funny about these things.

Answer (score 0):

So after 2 days of trying everything under the sun, turns out the problem was because the new Web Optimisation tools seem to run under .Net v4.5. Unfortunately the server didn't have v4.5 installed, so I installed it and now the bundles are created as expected.

Hope this helps someone.